# R: Changes to data when changing class

Tags: r

Prior to running a `randomForest` model, I load my data and sort variables into categorical and numerical so the model can process it.

Data as first loaded from the `.csv` file looks like this:

```
> str(DataFrame)
'data.frame':   1060 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ VarX   : int  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Var1   : num  127 135 137 138 138 ...
 $ Var2   : Factor w/ 200 levels "#N/A","1690",..: 190 190 190 191 191 191 189 185 183 181 ...
 $ Var3   : Factor w/ 138 levels "#N/A","100","101",..: 44 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 42 ...
 $ Var4   : int  15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 ...
 $ Var5   : Factor w/ 189 levels "#N/A","10029",..: 87 87 87 87 87 85 85 85 85 85 ...

> head(DataFrame, 3)
  VarX  Var1    Var2  Var3  Var4 Var5
1     1 126.58  3660  152   15   7159.5
2     1 135.17  3660  150   15   7159.5
3     1 137.25  3660  150   15   7159.5
```

I then attempt to sort the variables in the following way:

```
##Sort numerical and categorical values
options(digits = 5)

cols <- c("VarX")
for (i in cols) {
DataFrame[,i] = as.factor(DataFrame[,i])
}

cols2 <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5")
for (i in cols2) {
  DataFrame[,i] = as.numeric(DataFrame[,i])
}
```

However, this does something strange and undesirable to the data:

```
> str(DataFrame)
 'data.frame':  1060 obs. of  6 variables:
$ VarX   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
$ Var1   : num  127 135 137 138 138 ...
$ Var2   : num  190 190 190 191 191 191 189 185 183 181 ...
$ Var3   : num  44 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 42 ...
$ Var4   : num  15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 ...
$ Var5   : num  87 87 87 87 87 85 85 85 85 85 ...

> head(DataFrame,3)
  VarX  Var1    Var2  Var3  Var4   Var5
1     1 126.58   190   44   15      87
2     1 135.17   190   43   15      87
3     1 137.25   190   43   15      87
```

Also, while not shown in the above excerpt it turns all `NA` values into `1`, which, depending on the data, can skew the results.

**Q: What would be the correct way to process the data so that there is no corruption of the data, while ensuring that it can be used by the `randomForest` package?**

Comment: I simply changed it to more generic terms as the particular data wasn't of relevance to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have used `as.numeric(as.character(variable_name))` to convert a factor column to numeric column, otherwise information will be lost.

If you see the documentation of ?factor it says in the WARNING section:

> The interpretation of a factor depends on both the codes and the
>   "levels" attribute. Be careful only to compare factors with the same
>   set of levels (in the same order). In particular, as.numeric applied
>   to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To
>   transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values,
>   as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient
>   than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

Instead of for loops you can also use the power of sapply to convert these column into numeric like below:

```
dfnew <- sapply(df[,colms_to_be_converted],function(x)as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```